# Java: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException [indexOutOfBoundsExeption]

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to make an array from user input(Scanner) and then to show output the sorted array from the biggest member to the lowest but it goes outofbounds i dont know why , here is the source:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
public class U{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type array size: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    int[] numrat = new int[size];
    int[] renditur = new int[numrat.length];
    int numri;
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<numrat.length;i++){
        System.out.print("Type a number: ");
        numrat[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }

    int index=0;    

    for(int i=0; i<renditur.length ;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<renditur.length ;j++){
            if(numrat[i] > numrat[j]){
                renditur[index++]=numrat[i];

            }
            else{
                renditur[index++]=numrat[j];                
            }

        }
            renditur[index++]=numrat[i];
    }

    //after sorting from the biggest..
    for(int i=0;i<renditur.length;i++){
        System.out.print(renditur[i] + " ");        
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code snippet your inner loop will run until `j < renditur.length` condition will be true.

Now, next you are doing is `renditur[index++] = numrat[i];`. But remember that `i` is already equals the size of `renditur - 1` and hence it will give you `ArrayOutOfBounds` Exception.

```
for(int i = 0; i < renditur.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < renditur.length; j++) {
        if(numrat[i] > numrat[j]) {
            renditur[index++]=numrat[i];
        }
        else {
            renditur[index++]=numrat[j];                
        }

    }
    renditur[index++]=numrat[i];
}
```

You'll either have to reset the counter or correct your logic to not to do the following once your inner loop finishes:

```
renditur[index++]=numrat[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already increasing the value of i and j in for loops, and again in the inner conditions, so it is going out of range.

```
for(int i=0; i<renditur.length ;i++){
    for(int j=0; j<renditur.length ;j++){
        if(numrat[i] > numrat[j]){
            renditur[index++]=numrat[i];

        }
        else{
            renditur[index++]=numrat[j];                
        }

    }
        renditur[index++]=numrat[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning of the second iteration of the `j` loop the `index` variable is equal than the lenght of `renditur` (out of `renditur` bounds). When you try to do `renditur[index++]` next, the exception is raised because `index` is out of `renditur` bounds. Check the algorithm, some thing is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is wrong. You could add

```
if (index < renditur.length) {
renditur[index++] = numrat[i];
}
```

to avoid outofbounds exception, but it would not sort the array correctly anyway.

You have two options:

a) Use Arrays.sort (easiest option):

```
Arrays.sort(numrat); // sort array
ArrayUtils.reverse(numrat); // reverse sorted array
```

b) Write your own sorting method from already avaliable sorting methods (quicksort, merge sort, heapsort, bubble sort. e.t.c.) and then reverse the array.